# How to fix JPA in Spring Boot error IllegalStateException: The column type is undefined?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA + Spring Boot for my project. This is the first time I'm using JPA and I'm also very new to Spring Boot.

I want to create two tables `file_perms` and `file_perm_values`. I am able to get the definition of `file_perms` right. However, for my second table `file_perm_values`, I want to define a composite primary key that consists of the primary key of the `file_perms`, i.e., `id` and another String `file_id`. When I write the definition shown below and use the DDL creation button of Intellij, I get the error `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The column type is undefined. Table - file_perm_values; Column - file_perm_id`

What am I doing wrong?

Could some of the experts out there please help me understand what's the problem and how to fix this?

I'll be very grateful

```
package com.some.project.persistence.model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Getter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Table(name = "file_perms")
public class FilePermsEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Builder.Default
    @ToString.Include
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private UUID id = null;

    @ToString.Include
    @Column(name = "perm_name", nullable = false)
    private String permName;

    @ToString.Include
    @Column(name = "is_active", nullable = false)
    private boolean active;

    @ToString.Include
    @Column(name = "perm_guid")
    private String permGuid;

    @ToString.Include
    @Column(name = "perm_index")
    private int permIndex;

    @CreatedDate
    @Builder.Default
    @ToString.Include
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private ZonedDateTime createdAt = ZonedDateTime.now();

    @Builder.Default
    @ToString.Include
    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private ZonedDateTime updatedAt = ZonedDateTime.now();
}
```

```
package com.some.project.persistence.model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.MapsId;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@ToString(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Table(name = "file_perm_values")
public class FilePermValuesEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    @ToString.Include
    private FilePermValuesPrimaryKey id;

    @ToString.Include
    @Column(name = "value")
    private String value;

    @Getter
    @Builder
    @Embeddable
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @ToString(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
    public static class FilePermValuesPrimaryKey implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1223232L;

        @MapsId
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "file_perm_id", nullable = false)
        private FilePermsEntity filePermsEntity;

        @ToString.Include
        @Column(name = "file_id", nullable = false)
        private String fileId;

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try removing the `@MapsId` from `FilePermValuesPrimaryKey#filePermsEntity`

Comment: Thank you, Christian. That solved my issue. I will post my answer so that it will clarify the Q and help others too

Answer (score 0):

The code below solved my problem:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@ToString(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Table(name = "file_perm_values")
public class FilePermValuesEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    @ToString.Include
    private FilePermValuesPrimaryKey id;

    @MapsId("filePermId")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "file_perm_id")
    private FilePermsEntity filePermsEntity;

    @ToString.Include
    @Column(name = "value")
    private String value;

    @Getter
    @Builder
    @Embeddable
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @ToString(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
    public static class FilePermValuesPrimaryKey implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1223232L;

        @ToString.Include
        @Column(name = "file_perm_id", nullable = false)
        private UUID filePermId;

        @ToString.Include
        @Column(name = "file_id", nullable = false)
        private String fileId;

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```